# Checking if an element exists without losing time in Capybara

Tags: cucumber, automated-tests, capybara

I like to keep things DRY, that's why I want to have the following in one of my steps:

```
if first(:css, "#blabla") != nil
    find_by_id(blabla).click
end
find_by_id(....)
....
```

This means, that it will look for a certain element, and if it exists, it will click on it. If not, I will not lose time (my default wait time is 20 secs, which will be used if I put `find`  instead of `first` there.

The main issue is that I don't want to lose time when checking for a certain element in this case, but I am also wondering if this is a good approach.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I see the issue that your code does unnecessary second query to browser (you already have `first(:css, "#blabla")` so no need to do `find_by_id(blabla)`)

I propose you to find element using one query:

```
el = first('#blabla')
el.click unless el.nil?
```

Note that there is no losing time here as `first` doesn't block.

However, `first` doesn't check that there no other elements on the page. You can add `:maximum` to check it:

```
el = first('#blabla', maximum: 1)
el.click unless el.nil?
```

Comment: The updated answer is very helpful. Thank you! I have changed my code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you're using `#find` to decide on element presence, you should reduce the wait time for just that call:

```
if page.has_css?('#blabla', wait: 0)
  # Do something
end
```

However, in your special case, the suggested solution is even better, because it saves you multiple "find" calls for the same element.